# Piping Readable -> Writable streams -- emit vs data?

Tags: node.js, stream, binary, websocket, typed-arrays

I have some code which uses max ogden's websocket-stream library (https://github.com/maxogden/websocket-stream), which is pretty nifty.

When I do this:

```
websocketStream.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I get an ArrayBuffer in the client (what I want, this is a binary websocket stream).

When I try to implement a writable stream (using prototypes or whatever), I'm getting an ArrayBufferView in _write instead of the bare ArrayBuffer :-(. I'm using objectMode:true.

The simplest example is:

```
var s = new Writable({objectMode:true});
s._write = function(chunk, enc, next){
    console.log(chunk); // an arraybufferview
    console.log(enc); // `buffer`
    next();
}
websocketStream.pipe(s);
```

Who's newing up the buffer view, and how can I stop them?

The workaround is to take the chunk in write and grab the .buffer. But I'm doing my best to understand the 'implementors' side of the newer streams interface, and would love to do things correctly.

Comment: If you receive binary data, why do you use `objectMode: true`? It looks like `websocketStream` sends Buffers objects, so you should be fine without any special option.

Comment: @PaulMougel - I get very odd behavior when I don't set objectMode to true. I started that way, since it stands to reason I'm passing around buffers, so thats good right?

Comment: @PaulMougel - however, it _write receives nothing after the first chunk. It plays 64k of daya or some such and then stops. I either don't understand some fundamental precondition of inheriting from Stream.Writable, or its a quirk of bringing it to the browser with Browserify. I'm not getting a node Buffer object, right -- its an "ArrayBuffer" which is the browsers untyped array variant. Not sure if nodes core stream implementation is aware of it...

Comment: Per [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_writable_options), if `objectMode` is set to false, then you can only write strings or Buffer; if it's true, then you can write arbitrary objects. This means that in order to get Buffers to work properly with streams, you should set `objectMode` to false (otherwise the backpressure will be weird for instance, since one buffer object will count as 1, instead of `buffer.length`). However, I have no experience with `ArrayBuffer`, you should raise the issue on browserify's bug tracker.

Comment: If your issue is that your stream stops after exactly 64k of data, this sounds like the stream is not consuming the data properly, i.e. that the stream implementation doesn't know that your Writable stream has consumed the data and acknowledged that fact by calling `next()`. Otherwise the streams module thinks that your stream hasn't processed the data and then the backpressure kicks in (so that your stream isn't overloaded).

Comment: @PaulMougel, sounds like a bug with browserify or websocket-stream then. I updated the example. I'm definitely always calling next() in the actual implementation and I know about the backpressure mechanics.